# Accessing members of composite sorts (data types) in SMT-LIBv2

Tags: smt, model-checking, cvc4

According to sec. 3.9.3 of [The SMT-LIBv2 Language and Tools: A Tutorial](http://www.grammatech.com/resources/smt/SMTLIBTutorial.pdf) it is possible to declare a composite sort like this in SMT-LIBv2:

```
(set-logic QF_UF)
(declare-sort Triple 3)
(declare-fun state () (Triple Bool Bool Bool))
```

I am using CVC4 and it seems to accept this syntax. But how do I access the elements? I tried the following (and various variations of that and other things I found online):

```
(assert (_ state 1))
(assert (select 1 state))
```

But it looks like those operators only work on vectors and arrays. I can't find any example that uses such composite sorts and can't find anything about accessing those elements in the tutorial or the language standard. How is it done? Or did I completely misunderstand what this feature is for?

My application: I want to encode a temporal problem and want to do it in form of a state transition function that converts the old state into a new state, so I can write something like the following when experimenting with the system:

```
....
(declare-fun initial_state () MyStateSort)
(declare-fun state_after_step_1 () MyStateSort)
(declare-fun state_after_step_2 () MyStateSort)
(assert (= (MyTransitionFunc initial_state) state_after_step_1)
(assert (= (MyTransitionFunc state_after_step_1) state_after_step_2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*This is an answer to my own question. If anyone can post an example for a use-case of a user-defined sort with arity > 0, I'll happily accept that as answer.*

After reading the SMT-LIBv2 standard more carefully I am now thinking that sort declarations with arity > 0 only have an application in theory definitions (for declaring sorts like `Array`), not in user-supplied code. The example in David Cok's Tutorial seems to be misleading, as it suggests that this can be used to declare composite sorts. I have not found any indication of that anywhere else. This includes the complete SMT-LIB benchmark that contains not a single sort declaration with arity > 0.

Instead of "composite sorts" one should use uninterpreted functions to create the equivalent of complex data structures. Example:

```
(set-logic QF_UF)
(declare-sort CONTAINER_SORT 0)
(declare-fun CONTAINER_MEMBER_1 (CONTAINER_SORT) Bool)
(declare-fun CONTAINER_MEMBER_2 (CONTAINER_SORT) Bool)
(declare-fun INSTANCE_1 () CONTAINER_SORT)
(declare-fun INSTANCE_2 () CONTAINER_SORT)
```

This will effectively declare the following 4 independent Bool expressions.

```
(CONTAINER_MEMBER_1 INSTANCE_1)
(CONTAINER_MEMBER_2 INSTANCE_1)

(CONTAINER_MEMBER_1 INSTANCE_2)
(CONTAINER_MEMBER_2 INSTANCE_2)
```

Comment: This is mostly right. The declare-sort command makes new sort functions. These can be applied to generate new sorts. However, if the sort does not have an associated theory it is uninterpreted. So (Array CONTAINER_SORT CONTAINER_SORT) is an application of the Array function to a user made constant sort symbol CONTAINER_SORT. As Array has a theory all makes sense. The Triple you declared above does not so an application generates a new sort symbol with an uninterpreted domain.

Comment: As for encoding simple datatypes, I would recommend looking into the theory of [inductive datatypes](http://www.cs.nyu.edu/~barrett/pubs/BST07-JSAT.pdf). In "smt2", cvc4 follows z3's extension for this. (cvc3/4 supports this theory in CVC language as well as the apis. Also, yices's syntax supports non-recursive datatypes.) See the following for examples: [rise4fun](http://rise4fun.com/z3/tutorial), [cvc4's input examples](https://github.com/CVC4/CVC4/tree/master/test/regress/regress0/datatypes), and [cvc4's api example](https://github.com/CVC4/CVC4/blob/master/examples/api/datatypes.cpp).